# Problem upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.01

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 15.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.01 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T410 and the upgrade has frozen while unpacking libyates 5.2.0 and the terminal screen has a microsoft EULA for configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer which appears to require acceptance but the  button isn't really there as it is a txt doc.
What to do??

Answer (score 0):

In the EULA use the tab key to navigate between the choices and the enter key to select one.